# LaTeX/MathJax Quick Guide

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Tutorials too long. Quick guide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

---

$x$

```
$x$
```

---

$$
x + y^{2k}
$$

```
$$
x + y^{2k}
$$
```

---

Inline $x + y$ with text

```
Inline $x + y$ with text
```

---

$$
a \leq \frac{b}{c}
$$

```
$$
a \leq \frac{b}{c}
$$
```

---

$$
y[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{m} b_k 
$$

```
$$
y[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{m} b_k 
$$
```

---

$$
\mathbf M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & \pi \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
$$

```tex
$$
\mathbf M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & \pi \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

---

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat\psi_{a,b}(\omega) d\omega, \omega \in \mathbb{R} 
$$

```
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat\psi_{a,b}(\omega) d\omega, \omega \in \mathbb{R} 
$$
```

[Greek Alphabet](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Greek_alphabet)

[Math symbols](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Exiangwen/pdf/LaTeX-Math-Symbols.pdf)

---

$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2, & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
\sqrt{3n+1}, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

```
$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2, & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
\sqrt{3n+1}, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
```

---

\begin{align}
5 &= 0.5^{-1} + 3 \\
&= 2 + 3 \\
&= \boxed{5} \tag{1}\label{1} \\
\end{align}

```
\begin{align}
5 &= 0.5^{-1} + 3 \\
&= 2 + 3 \\
&= \boxed{5} \tag{1}\label{1} \\
\end{align}
```

And in $\eqref{1}$ we see that the result is five.

```latex
And in $\eqref{1}$ we see that the result is five.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Advanced

[MathJax reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/450085) -- `$$` omitted below

$$
\mathbf I =
\begin{pmatrix}
  1      & 0      & \cdots & 0\\
  0      & 1      & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0      & 0      & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

```
\mathbf I = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1      & 0      & \cdots & 0\\
  0      & 1      & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0      & 0      & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
```

---

$$
\cos(\omega_0 t) \Leftrightarrow \pi \delta(|w| - \omega_0)
$$

```
\cos(\omega_0 t) \Leftrightarrow \pi \delta(|w| - \omega_0)
```

Comment: Feel free to add stuff here, I rather keep the main answer simple

Answer (score 1):

See the [Math.SE MathJax FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/510296) for a very long tutorial, a much shorter version is available at the [Operations Research MathJax FAQ](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/234/51); which adds particularly [helpful links](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/372/51) to this information:

"There are aids available to convert drawings, PDFs, and images to MathJax:

- [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) - Draw a shape or symbol and it is converted to the closest (guessed) **MathJax** equivalent.
- [ShapeCatcher](https://shapecatcher.com) - Draw a shape or symbol and it is converted to the closest (guessed) **Unicode** symbol.
- [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/#downloads) - Convert PDFs, images, and more to MathJax using an Android or Apple application. Free and paid versions available.".

Comment: Nice addition! Thank-you.