# Change MathJax Help Link for SE.SP

Tags: discussion

Let's change the MathJax help link for the SE.SP site to something more directly relevant for our users.

Comment: Did you have something else in mind or were you considering deleting the tag entirely?

Comment: @DanBoschen In order to link the MathJax help to an [answer here on meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1721/80), I need community support. Apparently there is none. :-)

Comment: I see- I always refer to this one: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  Not sure if this offers something not already there or if this should be simply added there together with that one. (?)

Comment: The suggestion was that that one is too over-the-top.